# Enable ed25519 in Debian wheezy

Tags: debian, ssh, encryption

In Debian 7 it seems like ssh doesn't accept ed25519 keys.

support for ECDSA was not added until end of 2013, but wheezy is older

How do I enable this in Debian 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are updated openssh client and server packages in Wheezy Backports.

According to the [changelog](http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs//main/o/openssh/openssh_6.6p1-4~bpo70+1_changelog), the backported version can work with ED25519 keys:

> openssh (1:6.6p1-4~bpo70+1) wheezy-backports; urgency=low
>
> - Rebuild for wheezy-backports.
>
>   -- Colin Watson   Wed, 30 Apr 2014 09:59:29
>     +0100
>
> [...]
>
> openssh (1:6.5p1-1) unstable; urgency=medium
>
> [...]
>
> - Generate ED25519 host keys on fresh installations.  Upgraders who
>     wish
>     to add such host keys should manually add 'HostKey
>     /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key' to /etc/ssh/sshd_config and run
>     'ssh-keygen -q -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key -N "" -t ed25519'.
>
>   -- Colin Watson   Mon, 10 Feb 2014 14:58:26
>     +0000

To install wheezy-backports packages, follow the [instructions](http://backports.debian.org/Instructions/).  In short, you need to add the following line to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-backports main
```

It would be wise to carefully read the backports site before making use of the repo.

Comment: Worked with `apt-get -t wheezy-backports install openssh`

Comment: It's actually ```apt-get -t wheezy-backports install openssh-server``` these days. There is no (more a) openssh package.